# Pandas groupby, drop consecutive duplicates and return as dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-3.8

I got a dataframe that I want to groupby the column 'a' and then remove the continuous duplicates within the groups to return a dataframe.

For example, if dataframe is

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12], 'b':['The Effect','effective','more','more','more','b','b','b','a'], 'c':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})`

```
>>> df
    a           b  c
0  11  The Effect  1
1  11   effective  2
2  11        more  3
3  11        more  4
4  12        more  5
5  12           b  6
6  12           b  7
7  12           b  8
8  12           a  9
```

my output should be

```
>>> df
    a           b  c
0  11  The Effect  1
1  11   effective  2
2  11        more  3
3  12        more  5
4  12           b  6
5  12           a  9
```

In reality, the dataframe is huge, containing more than 12 million entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to compare your data with it's shift:

```
d = df[['a','b']]
df[d.ne(d.shift()).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
    a           b  c
0  11  The Effect  1
1  11   effective  2
2  11        more  3
4  12        more  5
5  12           b  6
8  12           a  9
```

Comment: I corrected the question to reflect the effect of the groupby operation. I have other unique columns in the data frame.

Comment: @Shew see updated answer. You only need to shift and compare on the two columns of interest.

Comment: doesn't $d = df[['a','b']]$ create a temporary copy ?  my data frame is huge containing more than 12 million rows. will it create an issue ?

Comment: No, most likely it would create a slice. `d.shift()` creates a temporary copy, so does `ne`. But I wouldn't worry about that on 12 million rows :-).